# Change IMEI Genymotion Free Version

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, genymotion

You can change the IMEI using the Genymotion? Is there any way to perform these task?

[image: IME]

Answer (score 12):

Even though this question was asked 2 years ago, if  still someone needs an answer.

Open the folder which has the genymotion device image (you can find the path on the Settings menu in virtualbox), open the *.vbox file using any editor (notepad++ for example) and edit the 'genymotion_device_id' field with the desired IMEI.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

- Fist you need route your device,
- then install XPOSED FRAMEWORK
  http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer
- then install: XPOSED IMEI Changer on GG play
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vivek.imeichanger

Open XPOSED FRAMEWORK on tab Modules, check the: XPOSED IMEI Changer
Ok now you can change the imei to what number you want by opening XPOSED IMEI Changer

Answer (score 0):

You can change the IMEI using Identifiers widget, sadly identifiers widget not available in free version

Answer (score 0):

the personal genymotion don't have IMEI - don't try to change it

Answer (score 0):

On the taskbar to your right click on ID. Here you can change your IMEI. The default is `000000000`.